# Validate fields with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, field

I'm trying to validate multiple fields with the same name. Here's a visual representation of what I'm working with:
[image]

My validation currently works if I don't hit the "Request Another Sample" button, which generates another set of "Manufacturer", "SKU", etc. If I do "Request Another Sample", that's where the form bypasses the verification and just submits.

Here's what the "Manufacturer" field HTML looks like:

```
<tr class="product-sample-field">
  <td width="25"></td>
  <td align="left" class="formLabel"><font color="red">*</font><label id="manufacturerLabel"><%=eclSystem.translate(silver.getLanguage(), "Manufacturer")%>&nbsp;</label></td>                      
  <td>
      <input class="inputFieldBody" type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" placeholder="Fishman" size="30" value="<%=manufacturer%>">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what the verification JS looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var submitcount=0;
function checkForm(form) {
var ok = true, msg = "", tempmsg;

resetLabels();

if ( (tempmsg = checkEmail(form)) != "") {
    document.getElementById('emailLabel').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('confirmEmailLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.email.focus();
    form.confirmEmail.focus();
    msg += tempmsg;
    ok = false;
}
// pre-format the phone number
form.phone.value = phoneFormat(form.phone.value);
result = phoneRXP.exec(form.phone.value);
// phone #'s may contain ext number
if (!result) { 
    document.getElementById('phoneLabel').style.color = "red";
    if (form.phone.value)
        msg += "\r\n<%=eclSystem.translateJS(silver.getLanguage(), "Please enter a valid telephone number")%>";
    form.phone.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.firstName.value) {
    document.getElementById('nameLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.firstName.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.lastName.value) {
    document.getElementById('nameLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.lastName.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.company.value) {
    document.getElementById('companyLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.company.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.address.value) {
    document.getElementById('addressLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.address.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.city.value) {
    document.getElementById('cityStateZipLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.city.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.state.value) {
    document.getElementById('cityStateZipLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.state.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.zip.value) {
    document.getElementById('cityStateZipLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.zip.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.manufacturer.value) {
    document.getElementById('manufacturerLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.manufacturer.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.sku.value) {
    document.getElementById('skuLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.sku.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.description.value) {
    document.getElementById('descriptionLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.description.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.size.value) {
    document.getElementById('sizeLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.size.focus();
    ok = false;
}
if (!form.quantity.value) {
    document.getElementById('quantityLabel').style.color = "red";
    form.quantity.focus();
    ok = false;
}

if (!ok) {
    // error message
    var finalmsg = "<%=eclSystem.translateJS(silver.getLanguage(), "Please correct the fields marked in red.")%>\r\n";
    if (msg) finalmsg += msg;
    alert(finalmsg);

    return false;
}

if (submitcount==0) {
    submitcount++;
    return true;
} else {
    alert('<%=eclSystem.translateJS(silver.getLanguage(), "This form has already been submitted. Thanks!")%>');
    return false;
    }
}

function resetLabels() {
document.getElementById('nameLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('companyLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('addressLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('cityStateZipLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('phoneLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('emailLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('confirmEmailLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('manufacturerLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('skuLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('descriptionLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('sizeLabel').style.color = "#000000";
document.getElementById('quantityLabel').style.color = "#000000";
}

function checkEmail(form) {
var msg = "";
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var confirmEmail = document.getElementById('confirmEmail');

if (form.email.value == "" || form.confirmEmail.value == "") 
    msg = "    "; // will flag error w/o msg
else if (email.value != confirmEmail.value)
    msg = "\r\n<%=eclSystem.translateJS(silver.getLanguage(), "Please confirm email addresses match.")%>";
else if (!emailRXP.exec(form.email.value) || !emailRXP.exec(form.confirmEmail.value))
    msg = "\r\n<%=eclSystem.translateJS(silver.getLanguage(), "Email address should use the following format: john@mycompany.com")%>";
   
return msg;
}

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need more information as well.

Comment: multiple elements can not have the same id. If you are duplicating you are going to have to use the name field and loop over the collection of elements.

Comment: Additionally, multiple form fields cannot have the same name unless 1) you are going to loop through them with javascript and assemble form data by DOM heirarchy or 2) you use the array brackets [] to signify the element will go to the back end as an array, like `name="manufacturer[]"`

Comment: Can you include all of your validation code? In my experience, if there's an unhandled error, it'll submit anyway.

Comment: @user1599011 Added all of the validation code. Sorry the formatting...

Comment: Where is `checkForm()` called from? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: checkForm() is called in the HTML on the form itself. 

<form action="<%=processloc%>" method="POST" name="ContactForm" id="ContactForm" target="_self"  onsubmit="return checkForm(ContactForm)" >

Comment: There is a console error! Although it happens so quickly when the form processes. "form.manufacturer.focus is not a function"

Comment: `form.manufacturer.focus();` will fail if you have anywhere in your document two of these
`<td><input class="inputFieldBody" type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer"></td><td><input class="inputFieldBody" type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" ></td>`

Comment: Yup, that's what I suspected. Thing is, I'll have two of those td's when clicking the "Request Another Sample" button. Is there a different way around this? I tried adding a class name to the input and then replacing form.manufacturer.focus(); with document.getElementsByClassName('mfr').focus(); but that doesn't work either

Comment: Wait. No wonder... of course you can't focus multiple elements with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only submit when you click the *Request Another Sample* button, I see two possible solution: 1) Don't use a button element, instead of a button element you can use a span designed as a button. or 2) If you will rather use the button element then you'll need to prevent it from submitting the form anytime it's clicked. See the JS to prevent Submission below:

```
const
    request_btn = document.querySelector('#request-btn')

request_btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // The anything the button needs to here
})
```

When it comes to form validation consider add the required attribute to the input and select elements, this will save you valuable time.

Comment: So the form isn't being submitted when I click the "Request Another Sample" button. The form isn't validating when I click "submit" if there's multiple fields with the same name if that makes sense.

Comment: You can use a `<button>` element without it submitting by specifying the [button type](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) ... `<button type="button">` — using a span is _bad_ for accessibility.

Comment: @StephenP is absolutely right. Span is bad for accessibility so you should probably set the button type to `button`

Comment: @Marc the name attribute shouldn't affect your form validation nor submission. It's probably the way you wrote the validation code that's problematic.